# How send many requests over a single TCP connection without wait responses? C#

Tags: c#, .net, task, task-parallel-library, tcpclient

Currently, I'm trying to send many raw requests over a single connection in the faster way. I achieve that using HTTPClient lib but due the need of send raw bytes, I'm using TCPClient.

Some of requisites of this application:

- 1 connection
- Submit all of requets in a pipeline, , continuing to send without waiting for each read
- Send raw requests

What I have of code:

Method to send all requests

```
private static async Task SendAllRequests(Dictionary<int, string> requestsDictionary)
        {
            var client = new TcpClient();
            var ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];

            await client.ConnectAsync("localhost", 44392);
            SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(
                client.GetStream(),
                false,
                null
            );
            await sslStream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync("localhost");

            var tasks = new List<Task<KeyValuePair<int, SslStream>>>();

            foreach (var k in requestsDictionary.Keys)
            {

                tasks.Add(SendStreamAsync(requestString, sslStream));
            }

            var requestsInfo = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
       }
```

Method to send and read bytes of a single request

```
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int bytes;
 
            byte[] request = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestString);
            await sslStream.WriteAsync(request, 0, request.Length);
            await sslStream.FlushAsync();

            do
            {
                bytes = await sslStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            } while (bytes == 2048);
```

Currently behaviour:

[image: scriptbehaviour]

Comment: What you are running behind localhost:44392?

Comment: I'm testing the sending with a local web server

Comment: As Marc states in his answer: this is not as trivial as it may sound. That out of the way, I'd suggest you have a look into "message queues".

Comment: When ever you send the receive side need to be able to determine where the end of each message occurs.   So you have to use one of three methods 1) Terminate each message with a character that is not inside the message 2)  Add a byte count to beginning of the message 3) Use Fix size messages.  then on receive end parse messages according to the way there were sent.  When you send a response than only one message is sent at a time so you can read the entire message.  Note with TCP one send message can b e received in multiple chunks.

Comment: @jdweng currently I'm sending requests with the same size

Comment: Then receive end you have to parse input and split by the fixed message size.  Any extra bytes from one received message ahs to be saved and put into the input of next message.  You can also receive more than one message in the receive so you have to have a loop so when more than one message is received at same time both get parsed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to send multiple requests, you literally just: send multiple requests. It isn't clear what the question is here, or what unexpected behaviour you're seeing. However! A few considerations:

- while you don't need to await each *response*, you do need to await each *write* - you can't write concurrently to the same socket from two different contexts (which you do currently)
- TCP is a *stream*; there is no inherent framing - all that is guaranteed is that the same bytes will arrive in the right order (or failure, eventually); so: when sending multiple messages, **you** need to add the framing (so you know where each message starts and ends); this could be, for example, by CR/LF terminators in a text-based protocol, or by a length-prefix in a binary protocol
- when dealing with this kind of pipeline, you can't read as part of the write (as that would defy the point), so: you'll need a *separate* read loop that *just* reads replies, and correlates them back to requests if needed; this might mean a queue if replies are always ordered with regards to requests, or a dictionary if replies can be out of order, keyed by some correlation identifier
- honestly, this kind of network code is non-trivial

Comment: Yeah, It's for a very specific project. I had almost reached my goal using HTTPClient, but couldnt send custom bytes over the connection. Would you have any better suggestion for this problem?

Comment: oh, it is a common enough problem - it is very similar to the scenario used by SE.Redis (just something I maintain); however, it is a very *complex* problem - not one I can explain in a few lines